# Is there a HTML-RadioButton value equivalent in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I am trying to create a series of RadioButtons on a WinForm. It works OK, but in the Click-event I want to capture the product ID and do stuff with that. 
I am used to HTML-elements, and assigning data to a label and value for the RadioButton. With WinForms I cannot see the equivalent to the value attribute.

Any good advice on how to pass onn the product ID to the RadioButton Change-event?

```
var products = new Business.Products().GetAll();
if (!products.Any())
    GrpCategories.Controls.Clear();

int y = 2;
int x = 2;
foreach (var product in products)
{
    var btn = new RadioButton();
    btn.Width = 100;
    btn.Height = 20;
    if (y >= GrpCategories.Height - btn.Height - 10)
    {
        x += btn.Width + 2;
        y = 2;
    }
    y += btn.Height + 2;
    btn.Appearance = Appearance.Button;
    btn.Text = product.Name;
    btn.Name = "BtnProduct_" + product.ID;
    btn.Location = new Point(x, y);

    GrpCategories.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Comment: Do you actually need to use radio buttons, or would a single-selection list be more appropriate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the [`Tag`-property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx) of the `RadioButton`. This property can store any .NET object.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like  RadioButtonList control in winform or else it would have solved your problem like nothing.

But,then also You can group radio buttons by adding them inside a container such as a Panel control, a GroupBox control, or a form.

Drag a group panel inside your form and then add your radio buttons, this will group all the radio buttons inside that group.. [as is done here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sefz7fxc.aspx).

Comment: GrpCategories is a group-control.